# Remove anchor tag/hyperlinks from pdf using PDFSharp

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, pdfsharp

New to PDF Manipulation.  I see lots of stuff about iTextSharp but nothing that really suits me.  Our 3rd Party (Essential Objects) crashes when it tries to merge PDFs that have hyperlinks...so I need to strip them out (leaving the text) when the user uploads the PDF.  I'd love a quick resolution to this (as EO has not been very helpful)

Comment: In your question title and in the tags you refer to pdfsharp. In the text, though, you talk about iTextSharp. Which library do you actually mean?

Comment: Using PDFSharp to remove links.  It works unless the PDF was created in Acrobat 6+, then I get some error about it not being supported.